# Is it possible to loc a column based on a sort from another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following DataFrame, and I need to obtain only the values from Column 2 that go from 21 to 1, without losing the sorting from Column 1

| Column1 | Column2 | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 44508 | 20 | A |
| 44508 | 20 | B |
| 44509 | 21 | B |
| 44510 | 22 | C |
| 44511 | 1 | A |
| 44511 | 1 | B |
| 44512 | 2 | A |

This was my initial approach:

```
df= df.sort_values(by='Column1')
df = df.loc[(df['Column2'] >= 21) & (df['Column2'] <= 1)]
```

But it obviously didn't work as there won't be any value higher than 21 and lower than 1.

And I am trying to obtain this:

| Column1 | Column2 | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 44509 | 21 | B |
| 44510 | 22 | C |
| 44511 | 1 | A |

I also thought about first sorting the whole DataFrame, and then choose from the row where it is first found the 21 to the last time it is found the 1, but I could not anything about this approach, and I don't know if there might be a simpler solution to it.

PD: The Column 2 is a value generated based on column 1; I understand that a solution would be to just loc by column1 but I need it to be based on Column 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `loc` to slice the DataFrame with `idxmax` to get the index of the first occurrence of 1:

```
out = df.loc[df['Column2'].eq(21).idxmax() : df['Column2'].eq(1).idxmax()]
```

Output:

```
   Column1  Column2 Value
2    44509       21     B
3    44510       22     C
4    44511        1     A
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your condition

```
df = df.loc[~((dfmerged['Column2'] < 21) & (df['Column2'] > 1))]
```